# STM32MP157c SPI clock will not idle high

Tags: embedded-linux, stm32, spi

I am trying to run crystalfonts lcd cfaf240320a0024sc (https://www.crystalfontz.com/product/cfaf240320a0024sc-240x320-full-color-touchscreen-tft-2-4) with stm32mpu over SPI. The LCD controller is ST7789

I am using STM32MP157c that comes with octavo OSD32MP1-BRK.

OpenSTLinux kernel version is 5.4

I can interface the LCD easily with an arduino/seeduino. But it doesn't work with the octavo.

I wrote a clone of the arduino example program (https://www.crystalfontz.com/products/document/4222/CFAF240320A0-024SC_Arduino_SPI_bring_up.zip) using Linux userspace spidev interface. One thing I notice is that even though I have set CPOL=1, the clock never idles high. It always goes back to low.

I am using the following device tree block:

```
    &spi6 {
    pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
    pinctrl-0 = <&spi6_pins_mx>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&spi6_sleep_pins_mx>;
    cs-gpios = <&gpioz 3 0>;
    status = "okay";
    spi-cpol = <1>;
    spi-cpha = <0>;

   spidev6: spidev6@0{
    compatible = "rohm,dh2228fv";
    spi-max-frequency = <30000000>;
    reg = <0>;
    spi-cpol = <1>;
    spi-cpha = <0>;
  };
};
```

Also I have tried to pull up the relevant pins in the pinconfig block, and tried without this as well, but no luck:

```
    spi6_pins_mx: spi6-0 {
    pins1 {
      pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('Z', 2, AF8)>; /* SPI6_MOSI */
      bias-disable;
      drive-push-pull;
      slew-rate = <1>;
    };

    pins2 {
      pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('Z', 1, AF8)>; /* SPI6_MISO */
      bias-disable;
    };

    pins3 {
      pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('Z', 0, AF8)>; /* SPI6_SCK */
      bias-pull-up;
      slew-rate = <1>;
    };
  };
```

I have even tested with the LCD detached but it still idles low. I have verified that my device tree changes are running by turning onboard LEDs on and off.

Just before the SPI starts to transmit it becomes high and after the transmission is finished, it becomes low again. This is not acceptable as many cheap LCDs do not have a CS pin and they read based on clock edge not CS.

In the userspace spidev program, I am using the same SPI mode (2) as well

This question has already been asked here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/572302/278129

But no response was available on that community

Answer (score 0):

Thanks and all credits to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/289513/thomas-petazzoni

Original answer here:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/572341/278129

"the spi-stm32 driver uses runtime PM, which will automatically switch the pins to the "sleep" pin mux configuration when the SPI controller is not in use (after a certain timeout). It could be what you're seeing here. Try to disable runtime PM for the SPI controller, or"

It is going into the "spi6_sleep_pins_mx" pin configuration, where all SCK, MOSI etc pins are defined as "Analog".

If we remove "spi6_sleep_pins_mx" from the possible pin control configurations such that there is only one pinctrl configuration, it works.